# Specify folder name while upload file via Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Here is my code snippet:

```
    $service=new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file=new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($title);
    $file->setDescription('some desciption');
    $file->setMimeType($mimeType);
    $createdFile=$service->files->insert($file,[
        'data'          => $data,
        'mimeType'      => $mimeType,
        'uploadType'    => 'media'
        ]);
```

This uploads the file to the root of the google drive.

I want to change the upload location to another folder, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

never mind i found it myself
it seems that you need to instantiate a parent reference service and pass it to the parents method of your DriveFIle

```
$parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference(); 
$parent->setId('folderid');
$file->setParents(array($parent));
```