# Can't find my files in google drive that uploaded via Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am uploading files to my google drive account. This are the codes:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=xxxx.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$tempfile = "birds-image-11.jpg";

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(

        'name' => 'tc-test.jpg',

    ));

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$result = $service->files->create($file, array(
  'data' => file_get_contents($tempfile),
 'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'uploadType' => 'media',
  'fields' => 'id, name,kind'
));

printf("File ID: %s\n", $result->id);echo '<br>';
printf("File Name: %s\n", $result->name);echo '<br>';
printf("File Kind: %s\n", $result->kind); echo '<br>';
```

I can see the id, name and kind returned. So that's mean the files has been uploaded right? But When I goto my google drive, I can't see the files.

If I list the files from the api `$service->files->listFiles();` I can see the uploaded file object returned.

Why I can't see it in my drive (https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive) and where should I looked for the file?

By the way, I am using service account for the api.

Comment: `putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='xxxx.json');` <= This row contains syntax errors.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, fixed.

Comment: @dev-jim, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to set the file's parent folder(s), which can be the user's "My Drive" or any other folder(s).

[Specify folder name while upload file via Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017234/specify-folder-name-while-upload-file-via-google-drive-api?rq=1)

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update